# how render specific array of string in unorderlist

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a specific array of strings on this object however the result is showing in a single line. how can I fix this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data:[
      {
        id:0, 
        rating: 8, 
        movielist:['the mamoy', 'the black dragon', 'kung fu hustle', 'the tynilet']
      },
      {
        id:1, 
        rating: 5, 
        movielist:['the smalllet', 'the black pig', 'kung fu panda', 'the biglet']
      },
      {
        id:2, 
        rating: 7, 
        movielist:['the gift', 'breaking habit', 'shaman', 'the shark']
      },
      {
        id:3, 
        rating: 10, 
        movielist:['the algorithm', 'the kings', 'fighter devil', 'the shogun']
      },
    ]
  }
  
 
  
  render() {
    const {data} = this.state
    function RenderList(){
      const temp = data.filter(item => item.id === 3)
      return <ul>{temp.map(item => <span key={item.id}>{item.movielist}{`\n`}</span>)}</ul>
    }

    

    return (
      <div>
       
        {RenderList()}
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

the result showing like this
'the algorithmthe kingsfighter devilthe shogun'

my expectation would be

- the algorithm
- the kings
- fighter devil
- the shogun

Comment: Convert `span` to list item `li` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are simply rendering the nested `movielist` array directly into JSX, which is why it displays as a space-separated list.

## Solution

You should map the inner `movielist` array to list items.

I suggest first using `Array.prototype.find` to return the `data` item you want to render the `movielist` array of. If a match is returned conditionally render the `movielist` array into an unordered list (`ul`) element and map the movie items into list item (`li`) elements.

```
render() {
  const { data } = this.state;
  function renderList() {
    const temp = data.find((item) => item.id === 3);
    return temp ? (
      <ul key={temp.id}>
        {temp.movielist.map((listItem) => (
          <li>{listItem}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    ) : null;
  }

  return <div>{renderList()}</div>;
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 0,
        rating: 8,
        movielist: [
          "the mamoy",
          "the black dragon",
          "kung fu hustle",
          "the tynilet"
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        rating: 5,
        movielist: [
          "the smalllet",
          "the black pig",
          "kung fu panda",
          "the biglet"
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        rating: 7,
        movielist: ["the gift", "breaking habit", "shaman", "the shark"]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        rating: 10,
        movielist: ["the algorithm", "the kings", "fighter devil", "the shogun"]
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    function renderList() {
      const temp = data.find((item) => item.id === 3);
      return temp ? (
        <ul key={temp.id}>
          {temp.movielist.map((listItem) => (
            <li>{listItem}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : null;
    }

    return <div>{renderList()}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `span` to `li`
you will have sth like this

```html
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
</ul>
```